# Can't insert values into table through Visual Studio

Tags: c++, oracle, visual-studio

```
bool BDados::registar(string nome, string email, string gabinete, string sigla, string pass) {    

stringstream query;
        query << "INSERT INTO Docente VALUES (" << 7 << ",'" << nome << "','" << email << "','" << codigo << "','" << sigla << "','" << pass << "')";
        try{
            instrucao = ligacao->createStatement(query.str());
            ResultSet* re = instrucao->executeQuery();

            cout << "Registo efectuado com sucesso." << endl;
            return true;
        }catch (SQLException erro) {
            cout << erro.getMessage();
            return false;
        }
}
```

So I'm using this code to insert rows into my table Docente. But it doesn't do anything. The weird part is that no SQLException is thrown so in theory this should be working right or did I miss anything?

**EDIT:**
The problem was I thought executeUpdate commited automatically but apparently it doesn't. The solution was to add

```
ligacao->commit();
```

and to replace this `ResultSet* re = instrucao->executeQuery();`
with this `int a = instrucao->executeUpdate();`

Comment: It's possible the message in the exception could be useful in determining what caused the exception.   Why don't you edit your message and include that information?

Comment: No exception is thrown, taht's the point. It runs smoothly but without inserting anything.

Comment: Oops, sorry my mistake...I took a shot at an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you commit the changes to the DB?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause for this scenario is that you have two databases.

You are inserting into one but looking for the inserted record in another database.

Comment: If that was true, running it twice would blow up since it would violate the primary key constraint since I would be inserting twice an unique value. But it doesn't, I can run it how many times I want and nothing happens.

Comment: Not necessarily, most database use auto-incrementing integers as their primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs at [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28390/reference030.htm#LNCPP21660), you should use executeQuery for queries (which this isn't) and executeUpdate for inserts and updates (which this is).

Comment: That is also true. There was 2 problems with my code. I was using executeQuery instead of the right one (executeUpdate) and didn't commited the changes. Thanks for your help.